# Why isn't my HTML div working?

Tags: html, css

I made this thing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Experiment</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyway I added

```
div{
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
border: 4px solid black;
}
```

In CSS. Why doesn't it show up?
PS I am using text textastic code editor for ios.

Comment: Are you sure your stylesheet is being loaded?

Comment: Make sure your cache is not triggering, refresh a few times or turn caching off.

Comment: Where is your CSS for `div` being defined, and is it being included in your html file?

Comment: Thanks guys, it was a problem with my IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only issue might be that the CSS isn't loaded to the DOM of your webpage!

Try to inspect the error in the Console, or press F12 and see whether the file was loaded or not!

Your code is working perfect!

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/UHQ9F/ Here is the fiddle, you can see for yourself!

```
div {
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
border: 4px solid black;
}
```

So try this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/stylesheet.css'/>
```

Or this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='foldername/stylesheet.css'/>
```

Where folder name would be the name of the folder in which the stylesheet is placed!

Comment: You are using html5 so no need to include this attribute type='text/css' otherwise everything is fine.